# Styling of sub-controls which change their appearance based on bindings

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm, styles

I have a custom control bound to several properties and I want to separate styles but I'm facing a problem. 
Basically it is a Button with a ContentControl inside. The Button style depends on PropertyA (bool) but the ContentControls style depends on PropertyA and PropertyB (enum with 5 elements).

```
<Button Style="{Binding PropertyA, Converter={StaticResource styleSelector}}">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            [...]
            <ContentControl x:Name="cc1">
                <ContentControl.Template>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource contentSelector}">
                        <Binding Path="PropertyA" />
                        <Binding Path="PropertyB" />
                     </MultiBinding>
                 </ContentControl.Template>
            </ContentControl>
            [...]
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

The styles moved to resources

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyleA1" TargetType="Button">
   [...]
</Style>

<Style x:Key="ButtonStyleA2" TargetType="Button">
   [...]
</Style>
```

Because the ContentControl is part of the Button it should be possible to move the ContentControl's templates to `ButtonStyleA1` and `ButtonStyleA2` and reduce the dependency to PropertyB.
I tried use `<Setter ... TargetName="cc1">` in the styles but the compiler does not find cc1.
Do you have an idea for a simple and clean solution where the bindings remain in the Button?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: Hi Marc, not really. I'm still using the `contentSelector` based on the multi binding.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way might be to set the `ControlTemplate` property of your Button from within the Button style. Then you can define as many styles for the button as you want, each containing it's own `ControlTemplate` which are chosen based on the value of *PropertyA*.

In each ControlTemplate, you can set the Template for the content control to one of the five, using style triggers. You can define the templates for the content control either as a resource of the Button's `ControlTemplate` or somewhere else, depending on how you want to organize it.

I hope, I got your problem right and this helps in your case..

**EDIT:**

If you need to access your `ContentControl` from code behind, you can define **template parts** to do so.